# Where clause switch case on 2 boolean variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Looking for a query which executes where clauses based on boolean variables.

Something like:

```
select
    COUNT(col1)
from
    table1
where
    (@var1 is not null and col1 > @var1)
    and (@var2 is not null and col1 <= @var2);
```

Note the above query doesn't do what I need. I basically want:

```
If @var1 == NULL and @var2 == NULL THEN true
If @var1 == NULL and @var2 != NULL THEN col1 <= @var2
If @var1 != NULL and @var2 == NULL THEN col1 > @var1
If @var1 != NULL and @var2 != NULL THEN col1 > @var1 && col1 <= @var2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you gave up half way? Just continue as you started.

```
WHERE
    (@var1 IS NULL AND @var2 AND NULL)
    OR (@var1 IS NULL AND @var2 IS NOT NULL AND col2 <= @var2)
    OR (@var1 IS NOT NULL AND @var2 IS NULL AND col1 > @var1)
    OR (@var1 IS NOT NULL AND @var2 IS NOT NULL AND col1 > @var1 AND col2 <= @var2)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this would work but it was looking a bit messy. Was trying with using some better constructs provided by SQL Server, if possible.

Comment: @DimiAnsari define better? This is how you implement AND/OR logic, and you have 4 distinct conditions, which you may be able to simplify, but at the expense of clarity.

Comment: RIght, I think I'll go with this unless I'm able to find something better. Will update. Thank you for the help.

Comment: This could probably do with a `RECOMPILE` in the `OPTION` clause too. I suspect that a cached plan for when both values are `NULL` isn't going to be useful when only one or neither of them are (and vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this should work

```
where    ( 1= case when @var1 is  null and @var2 is  null then 1 else 0 end )
      OR ( case when  @var1 is null and @var2 is not null then col2<=@var2 
          end)
      OR ( case when @var1 is not null and @var2 is null then col1>@var1 end)
      OR ( case when @var1 is not null and @var2 is not null then col1>@var1 
           and col2<=@var2 end)
```